# Запуск веб приложения Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Только начал разбираться в Asp.Net. Подскажите существует ли простой локальный сервер для запуска веб приложения. Ибо IIS мне так и не удалось запустить, а Azure не подходит так как он не локальный.

Comment: IIS - самое простое, что можно придумать. Опишите подробнее, что значит "IIS мне так и не удалось запустить".

Comment: А у вас какая версия asp.net?

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio имеет внутри себя IIS Express, каковой используется и (как правило) стартует по нажатии кнопки F5 (Start Debugging)